# Raspberry Pi 3 crashes with 4 processes running gmpy, runs fine with 3 or less

Tags: linux, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, multi-threaded

I have written a Python program which uses homomorphic (paillier) encryption. For this I am using phe (https://github.com/n1analytics/python-paillier). Because this was really slow, I used 4 processes for the encryption. I then read that installing gmpy2 further speeds up the encryption. Now, when I am running my program with 4 processes (the Raspberry Pi has 4 cores) the whole OS crashes. When I only use 3 processes, nothing happens. How can I find out why that happens?

Comment: Sounds like you’re overloading something. Because the Pi can throttle itself, it’s most likely the power supply.

Comment: Great tip @DanielB! I will hook it up to a beefy power supply and try again.